# Windows Registry access for Python script

Tags: python-3.x, windows, registry

I'm working on a Python 3.7 script that eventually will be a CLI program like reg.exe is. I'm aiming to include the ability to add, delete and query keys and subkeys. At this point, I can create a new Key and iterate through all keys within the specific path however; once I try to write a value to the new key I made, I get a WinError 5 - Access denied.

Is there a way I can include in the script a way to have access to write to the registry?

I'm still a beginner with Python and programming, I've had a look at documents but I cant figure this one out.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. My code soo far:

```
import winreg

reg_connection = winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER)

reg_key = winreg.OpenKey(reg_connection, r"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\\")

winreg.CreateKey(reg_key, "New Key")

for key in range(3000):
    try:
        show_sub_keys = winreg.EnumKey(reg_key, key)
        print(show_sub_keys)
    except WindosError:
        break

new_key_value = winreg.OpenKey(reg_connection, r"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\New Key")
winreg.SetValueEx(new_key_value, "New Value",0,winreg.REG_SZ, "This Value")
winreg.CloseKey(new_key_value)
```

Comment: Don't use `ConnectRegistry` just to access the local registry. It maps a predefined key handle (i.e. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, `HKEY_USERS`, or `HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA`) to an RPC handle for remote registry access. `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` is a predefined-handle that by default maps to a handle for the current user's registry key, "\Registry\User\<User SID String>". This is meaningless for remote access (no user profile is loaded), so it's not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> new_key_value = winreg.OpenKey(reg_connection, r"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\New Key")
> ```

Here you do not specify an argument for the optional `access` parameter, so the call passes the default value of `KEY_READ`. Hence you can only read from the key, but not write.

You should pass an argument for the `access` parameter, that specifies the permissions you need:

```
new_key_value = winreg.OpenKey(reg_connection, r"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\New Key", 0, 
                               winreg.KEY_SET_VALUE)
```

For further details, see the [winreg reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winreg.html#access-rights).

Comment: Generally we request `KEY_READ` (i.e. `READ_CONTROL | KEY_NOTIFY | KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS | KEY_QUERY_VALUE`) and/or `KEY_WRITE` (i.e. `READ_CONTROL | KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY | KEY_SET_VALUE`) access, or equivalently `GENERIC_READ` and/or `GENERIC_WRITE` access.

Comment: @eryksun In the case of this question, only `KEY_SET_VALUE` is required. Requesting more access than needed would violate the [principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege). In particular, the DACL of a key may grant you permissions to write individual values, but prevents you from creating sub keys, in which case requesting `KEY_WRITE` would fail.

Comment: `winreg.CreateKey(reg_key, "New Key")`... really?

Comment: Thanks for the help on this one :) because im new to this, its a bit confusing at first, but I understand now what seems to be the better way from these suggestions. Thanks everyone. I'll review the Winreg library again until i understand it better.

Comment: If I need further help with the program, is it best to ask it here as its already the topic or does that need to be asked elsewhere?